# vpn (pptp) service failed to start

Tags: networking, vpn, pptp

When I try to connect to a VPN PPTP connection from Network Manager it fails with this message:

```
vpn connection failed because the vpn service failed to start.
```

It worked without any problem till I installed KVPNC application. I think that this app is the reason.

Comment: Are you running gnome? Have you tried removing the kvpnc package and trying again?

Answer (score 1):

As [justingrif](https://askubuntu.com/users/17828/justingrif) suggested did you try removing kvpnc and test?

Also try the below steps:

- "**Available to all user**" uncheck this option.
- Advanced settings -> Security and Compression -> check "**Use
  Point-to-Point encryption(MPPE)**" option.

Comment: there is no kvpnc package in ubuntu 14.04 and i checked using above two additional points, it donot work